# Sending Bulk Email With Size Limitation

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Problem :** I have got list of 1000 recipients, but I want to sent mail in batch of 200 each. I am using node js module **emailjs** for sending mail.

Below is my snippet of code.

```
 // Code goes here

 var sizeLimit = 200;
 var totalData = 350;
 var cycles = Math.ceil(totalData / sizeLimit);
 var start;
 var end;
 var recepients = "a@gmail.com,b@gmail.com...long list"

 for (var i = 0; i < cycles; i++) {
   start = end ? end + 1 : 0
   end = (sizeLimit) * (i + 1) > totalData ? (totalData - start) + start : 
   (sizeLimit) * (i + 1)


     var bcc = recepients.substr(start,end);

     (function(i) {
      setTimeout(function() {
       console.log(i)
       //Sending mail using emailjs 
       //bcc
       }, i * 5000)
     })(i)
  }
```

What is the best way of sending mail in batches, I don't want to use Redis.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather, you are attempting to send email batches by putting 200 recipients into the BCC field at once. This is extremely bad practice and shows a lack of understanding of the fundamentals of what you're trying to do.

What you should be doing instead is sending **one email to one recipient at a time**. This is what mailing list software does anyway and is what you should use for this purpose anyway instead of trying to roll your own.

You can use SaaS offerings like [MailChimp](https://mailchimp.com/), open source solutions like [Mailtrain](https://github.com/Mailtrain-org/mailtrain) or my personal favorite [Sendy](https://sendy.co/), which features API access, so you can automate certain aspects.

Comment: Interesting answer. Can you give a reason why it is "extremely bad practice"?

Comment: First, because you will not be listed as the recipient in the `To:` header. Aside from being perceived as unprofessional, it is often a sign of spam and may get you blocked. Then, there's limitations in mail servers which often severely limit the number of BCC recipients. One example is Gmail, which limits to 100 recipients — and that is actually quite generous. Also, you're putting considerable strain of the mail server by instructing it to send hundreds of mails out as fast as possible. Lastly, using your own mail server for sending out bulk mail will almost surely get you listed on a DNSBL.

Comment: Additionally, I recommend reading https://blog.codinghorror.com/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code/ on the complexities of email delivery.

Comment: Thanks @herrbischoff, it convinced me :)